# How to only display date only in datagridview that is populated by a database using SQL server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, datetime-format

My `DataGridView` date column is displaying a "dd/MM/yyyy 12:00:00 AM" format. I have looked and find [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246840/how-do-i-display-mm-dd-yyyy-no-time-in-my-datagridview-column), and used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29246980/9278485). But still the `DataGridView` is displaying all rows with 12:00:00 AM.

When I try to query the database

[image: Select date from the database]

[image: Data Type of Date]

But when I run the application and populate my `DataGridView`

[image: The date displays with 12:00:00 AM]

I tried adding this to my code, it still shows the 12:00:00 AM

```
dataGridCust.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"; //or
dataGridCust.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy"; //or
dataGridCust.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d"; //or all of them
```

or

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                dataGridCust.DataSource = dt;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridCust.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    dataGridCust.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value.ToString("d");
                }
```

If I change the for loop statement to

```
dataGridCust.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value.ToShortDateString();
```

It throws an error.

> CS1061  C# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToShortDateString' and no extension method 'ToShortDateString' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But when I run it on a lower OS (W7)

[image: It doesn't display 12:00:00 AM]

Why in W10, where I developed the app and where the sql server is, it displays 12:00:00 AM?

Other similar problems I saw and tried the solutions but no luck.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076712/display-only-the-date-format-in-datagridview)

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456538/convert-a-datagridview-cell-value-into-a-datetime)

[Similar question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2945b19e-3bef-4d1c-ad17-ffaaa385634f/setting-datacolumn-to-just-a-date-not-a-datetime?forum=csharpgeneral)

EDIT:

Windows 7 Region settings

[image: Windows 7]

Windows 10 Region settings

[image: Windows 10]

Comment: Because of different cultures/[regional settings] set on each machine.

Comment: _"C# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToShortDateString'"_ - `DataGridView` stores it's values inside objects, so first you need to cast `Value` to `DateTime`.

Comment: Time or no time should not be culture-dependent..

Comment: Could you please, check culture of your machine.

Comment: Setting the Column's Format should work, provided you do it to the right columns and after binding; it will not work if you do it before binding when the columns in the dgv are autogenerated, though..

Comment: You've set the `DefaultCellStyle`, have you tried the Columns CellTemplate property (as in `dataGridViewColumn.CellTemplate.Style.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy"`)?

Comment: As for culture/region settings of my machines will update the question and post the a screenshot. In W7 it displays M/d/yyyy, while in W10 it displays d MMM yyyy

Comment: I tried to match it on W7 it still attach 12:00:00 AM

Comment: @JayV I already diid but the time still displaying.

Comment: @TaW Yes I'm trying to change to format of Columns[11] or Columns["Date"] or Cells[11], they are all pointing the same column. And yes I'm formatting it after the binding.

Comment: Everytime I have used a DataGridView I would setup the columns and their formats BEFORE I set its DataSource and also set AutoGenerateColumns = false

Comment: If I format my datagridview before setting its datasource, it will return me an error 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'

Comment: You need to add the columns before you can format them.

Comment: @Jepher hope you are binding the source only once. rebinding the datasource wont be retain the columns format which you specified. better you set the column formatting next line to the datasource binding. like `DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
dataGridCust.DataSource = dt;
dataGridCust.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";`

Comment: @BaskarJohn. Yes, I tried 3 different format but still no luck.

Comment: That sounds really strange. For testing: Put the code with a fany format into a button and see if it makes any difference!

Comment: @TaW. This also stressing me out, this is the only datagridview that is acting strange, it is inside a tabpage with splitcontainer (this is the only difference with my other tabpage that have datagridview). My other datagridview is displaying what I wanted to be. Will create a new one, in a different project, and see what will happen.

Comment: Note that it should be visible to reflect any refreshes etc..!! (A tabpage bug, imo)

Comment: I simply created a table containing `Date` column, then using a `SqlDataAdapter` loaded data to `DataGridView`, after setting `DataSource` of `DataGridView` I changed format of the `Date` column of grid to `yyyy-MM-dd` using `dataGridView1.Columns["SomeDate"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";` and everything worked properly. I'm also using Windows 10.

Comment: You should be able to reproduce the problem and share a reproduction code/steps here, otherwise the question is subject to close as off-topic, because of not having [MCVE]

Comment: @RezaAghaei As I have said on the comments. This is only the datagridview that is having the problem. Its properties are the same with my other datagridview. I will try to create a new and similar project later.

Comment: @Jepher In these cases creating MCVE at the first step will help you to find the problem and solution yourself. Then if you couldn't find the solution yourself, it helps other users to reproduce the problem and share try to solve the problem. Unless it's not clear the problem they are trying to solve is the same as the problem that you have.

Comment: Deleted the previous dgv and created a new one, with same parameters. It is now displaying the right date. Why? Is it just a bug or something? I have spent hours thinking of a solution yesterday to fix the problem. Well, thank you very much for all your input. I'm still confuse why the dgv behaves like that.

Comment: @Jepher It probably has been a misconfiguration in DataGridView. For example, if the `ValueType` of the `Column` is not set to `DateTime` then the format which you are trying to apply, will not work. Anyway, you should never forget creating a clean MCVE. It's the correct path to find and solve problems.